# Transfer liferay files (documentt library) between two servers

Tags: liferay

I have built my liferay website in the development environment and now ready to be published. I have also installed two liferay nodes on two different servers where I want to put my website. Server1 is active and server2 as backup.

The problem is when I started the development, I didn't know I would one day need to have the two-server structure, so I stored all the documents and images on the file system and not to a database. So basically with this setting, when I make changes on server 1, I have to transfer the document library manually to server two, just like I would do for the themes.

I tried to change the document library location from the filesystem to the database in the portal-ext.properties, but that didn't help.

So, my questions:

- Is there a way to transfer these files to a database now, where they can be shared by both servers? and if not,
- Is it possible to somehow transfer the document library from server1 to server2 automatically through some script?

Thanks,

Adia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If server2 is a cold standby backup server and assuming you have a correct backup of the Liferay data directory of server1 and the database at the same moment in time, you can just restore the backup of the Liferay data directory to server2, restore the DB to the corresponding moment in time as the data directory backup and start server2.

In hot standby scenario's and clustered environments things get a little bit more complicated as you would need to use a common place to store documents, images, search indexes, etc... The easiest way is to store everything in the database or on a common file system so that multiple nodes are always working on the same data.

In you want to get your current set of documents that is stored on disk into the database the easiest way is to use the **Server > Server Administration > Data Migration** tab in the Control Panel. It has an option to migrate documents from the existing repository aka the disk to another, which would be the JCRStore in your case as that store can be configured to use the database.

Comment: Thanks fimez. Yep, I am now trying to migrate everytning to the database using that JCR option. One thing though; for the databasse URL parameter I have given this value: <param name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/liferayDB?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false"/>, but it is complaining about something, most probably the & operator, saying 'Invalid repository configuration file'. Any idea what I should right in the URL path? LiferayDB is my database, which I have been using from start.

Comment: It is possible that it is the & character that it's complaining about in which case you should be able to fix that by changing all the & characters to &amp;

Comment: Now I get these errors: 'Could not login to the workspace liferay' and 'Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'liferayDB')'. I have <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="liferay" /> just as it is the default and for the database. I have only defined a username; I haven't set a password for it all. So where do these come from? thanks.

Comment: You should define full database connection properties for all the sections in the repository.xml file; this means driver, url, user, password, schema and schemaObjectPrefix. You can also define a database in your application server and then refer to it from the repository.xml as a JNDI name, which simplifies the configuration a bit.

Comment: By the way, should the database be a totally new database or it doesn't matter if jackrabbit connects to an already existing database?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a new database (it will just add additional table to an existing one), but it can be if you want/need to.

Comment: If I create a new database, what about the data I have in the existing database? I wouldn't then be able to use a database dump to restore them, right?

Comment: The database connection properties you specify in the repository.xml are for additional tables that will be created and used. This extra data is used together with the existing database, so it won't replace it. That's why you can also just specify the existing database as nothing will be changed/removed with regards to the existing data.

Comment: Thanks a lot fimez. Finally it went through:) One big problem was that the maximum packet size on the database was small for the transfer to take place; after increasing that, everything went well. Thanks again and have a nice weekend.

Comment: Yet got a question if you could answer me. Now that I am trying to take all the .war files including the theme and a database dump from the development environment into a test server, after the deployment, I only see the header of my theme; It doesn't display any layout or content when I try through a browser. I have the same configurations in the reposiroty.xml and portal-ext.properties on the test server as they are in the development workspace. Is it correct that way? I mean should the settings be exactly the same? Thanks!

Comment: To replicate an existing Liferay server you do indeed need to copy over the config files, WAR files and the database content, but also the data directory as that contains the Lucene indexes (unless you use SOLR). To be sure it is also best if you start from a clean empty Liferay install so you're sure no preexisting stuff gets picked up.

Comment: Thanks fimes. One more thing: I have been using mysql DB instead of Hypersonic. When I added jackrabbit configuration to the portal-ext.properties, I commented out the DB configurations, because I thoguht since I have them in the respository.xml, I don't need them anymore in the portal-ext.properties. Do I need to have the DB configurations in the portal-ext.properties as well? I am asking because in the test server log I get 'Liferay is configured to use Hypersonic as its database.'. I didn't get this in the development environment, though there also I have removed the DB configurations.

Comment: Yes, you need to have both. The DB configuration in repository.xml only configures the DB for JackRabbit, but not for Liferay itself, that is done via the DB configuration in portal-ext.properties.

Comment: Right. I added it there. When the jackrabbit configurations are added and server restarted, a folder named home is created next to repository.xml file. Before whenever I deleted that and restarted the server, it would be created again, but not anymore after I uncommented the DB configurations in the portal-ext.properties. How to resote that? This is only in the development environment; on the test server it is created. Though, it is not causing any problem.

Comment: Now it is working on the test server as well. Thanks fimez for all your valuable comments.

Comment: One more question fimez. When I migrated everything from the document library to the database, I got the message that files have been migrated. Now that I created few new pages and uploaded few files, I see the document library got bigger in size; doesn't this mean that it is still saving to the document library? How can I make sure that it is saving to the databae? My settings in the portal properties file are as said on this link: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Document+Library+Migration+with+Jackrabbit, except this property: jcr.node.documentlibrary=documentlibrary

Comment: I don't really know what or why, but the only configuration I have for storing the document library in the database is a repository.xml file and 2 properties: dl.store.impl=com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.JCRStore
jcr.initialize.on.startup=true. What you could do to check is to make a backup of your Liferay installation, stop Liferay, delete everything but the configuration file(s) from the Jackrabbit directory and start Liferay again. If everything is configured correctly Liferay should start up and work without exceptions.

Comment: It is not writing one sigle bit to the database; I even removed all the JCR related properties in the properties file and wrote this line instead: dl.store.impl=com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.DBStore, but it is still putting the uploaded file in the documents library. Unbelievable!! Looks like it just ignores all my configurations.

Comment: Strange, I've got this kind of setup running in a Liferay cluster where local storage directories are useless and everything works correctly. I'm using a Liferay 6.1.1 CE GA2.

Comment: By the way, in the repository.xml file, I have the   <!--<Cluster id="node_1" syncDelay="5"> commented out. Could that be the problem?

Comment: If you're not actually working in a clustered environment that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Right; I am not using clustering. Uncommented that, but didn't help anyway. Now I am sure that nothing is saved to the DB. I deleted all the files that were added to the DB from the documents library and tried to upload some file from the Document and Media portlet; if this had worked, it should have added it to the DB and created tables like J_V_PM_BINVAL or J_V_PM_PROP; but it didn't:(

Comment: If your repository.xml file is valid and in the correct location <liferay>/data/jackrabbit, your portal-ext.properties is valid and in the correct location (root of your Liferay install) and you don't get any exceptions in the logging then I don't really know why it isn't working like it should in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot fimez. Now it is working. You know, I had a copy of the portal-ext.properties under mytheme/docroot/_diffs/WEB-INF and has made the chanages there, but looked like it just didn't read from it, while it should. After I put the jackrabbit properties in the portal-ext.properties in the ROOT folder, as you reminded, now it is saving to the DB. Thank you so much for all your patience and help.

Comment: can i transfer the doc lib from a Liferay 6.1.2 EE (Build 6130) to a 6.1.1 CE (Paton Build 6102) using the method discribed in this answer? from CE (older build) to EE (newer build) i suposse it would work

Comment: @MarceloBezerra: that is something I haven't tried. From an older to a newer version should work with the normal Liferay upgrade process, and I guess also between CE and EE, but for the other way around, newer to older, I fear you might run into trouble. What should always work is writing a small piece of Java that uses the Liferay webservices to iterate over the content of one Liferay and writes it to another, taking into account the API differences.